# Building array in loop with array push. Will using end() damage the array?

Tags: php, arrays

Maybe this is obvious, but `end()` returns the last array element and moves the pointer. It's that "moves the pointer" langauge that makes me nervous though. When using `array_push` or `$thearray[] = ""` or any other method of appending to the array, will the use of `end()` mean that the next added element will overwrite the last existing element?

Answer (score 1):

Only the array functions like `next`, `end`, `reset`, `each`, etc all use the array internal pointer.

`array_push()` will always push elements to the end of the array and things like `array_shift()` will always shift elements off the start.

To learn more about the internal pointer, check out [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28059372/what-is-an-array-internal-pointer-in-php)

Comment: Thanks! I guess that's covered then for what I'm doing, but in general, how can I tell which functions will use the array pointer and which won't?

Comment: Keep an eye on the documentation, they're pretty good about letting you know which ones do, they also call it an array cursor.